# How would I find $f(x+h)$ for $f(x)=4-x^2$?

Tags: calculus, functions

Can I see your work in full, too? I wanna see how you did it.

I got -2x-h, but was told it was incorrect.

Here's my work:

$\begin{align}
f(x) &= -1x^2+4x \\
f(x+h) &=-1(x+h)^2+4-(-1x^2+4)/h \\
 \\
\text{looking at }-1(x+h)^2+4\\
(x+h)^2 &= (x+h)(x+h)\\
&= x^2+xh+xh+h^2\\
&= x^2+2xh+h^2\\
\\
\therefore -1(x+h)^2+4 &= -1(x^2+2xh+h^2)+4\\
\\
\text{(?)so far }f(x+h) &=-1x^2-2xh-h^2+4-(-1x^2+4)\\
\\
-1(-1x^2+4) &= 1x^2-4\\
\\
\text{so far }f(x+h) &=-1x^2-2xh-h^2+4+1x^2-4\\
\\
\text{COMBINE LIKE TERMS}\\
\\
f(x+h) &= (-2xh-h^2)/h\\
&= -2x-h\\
\end{align}$

Comment: Did you mean $f(x) = 4 - x^2$ or $f(x) = 4x - x^2$.  Also, did you want to find $f(x + h)$ or the different quotient $\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$? Your work is inconsistent with the statement of the problem.

Comment: it is 4-x2! and i wanted to find f(x+h)! oh gosh, they ARE two different things. no wonder.

Comment: edited to layout more clearly, which makes very visible the issues here.

Answer (score 4):

To help you begin:

If $f(x)=4-x^2$, then $f(x+h)=4-(x+h)^2$

In general, the $x$ is replaced by whatever is in front of the $f$.

For example:

If I had $g(x)=2x^2+3x$, then $g(\smile)=2(\smile)^2+3(\smile)$. Also, $g(x^2+1)=2(x^2+1)^2+3(x^2+1)$

Answer (score 1):

You first need to know what $f(x)$ means. Can you see why when $f(x)=4-x^2$ that we also have $f(y)=4-y^2$? Or $f(h)=4-h^2$? The possibilities are endless. The case for $f(x+h)$ is a little more subtle, but two examples may clear things up.

**Example 1:** For $x=3$, we have $f(3)=4-(3)^2=4-9=-5$.

**Example 2:** For $x=7-4$, note that this is really $x=3$ but expressed differently, and we end up with the same thing:
\begin{align}
f(7-4)&= 4-(7-4)^2\\[0.5em]
&=4-[(7-4)(7-4)]\\[0.5em]
&=4-(7^2-4\cdot 7-4\cdot 7+4^2)\\[0.5em]
&=4-(49-28-28+16)\\[0.5em]
&=4-9\\[0.5em]
&=-5.
\end{align}
Now try this approach with your problem:
\begin{align}
f(x+h) &= 4-(x+h)^2\qquad\text{(plug $x+h$ into $f$)}\\[0.5em]
       &= 4-(x^2+2xh+h^2)\qquad\text{(FOIL)}\\[0.5em]
       &= 4-x^2-2xh-h^2\qquad\text{(simplify; possibly end here)}\\[0.5em]
       &= -x(x+h+2)-h(x+h+2)+2(x+h+2)\qquad\text{(manipulate)}\\[0.5em]
       &= (-x-h+2)(x+h+2)\qquad\text{(factor)}
\end{align}
I imagine that should be quite sufficient for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's start with a hint. Can you figure out what $f(y+h)$ is?